# Responsive Design and Percentages

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I am new to responsive design. I'm currently using Zurb's Foundation 4 to prototype a clients website.

I have an issue understanding, or should I say calculating percentages. For example, I have the following piece of HTML in my code:

```
<ul id="offers">
    <li class="small-6 large-3 columns">Offer 1</li>
    <li class="small-6 large-3 columns">Offer 2</li>
    <li class="small-6 large-3 columns">Offer 3</li>
    <li class="small-6 large-3 columns">Offer 4</li>
    <li class="small-6 large-3 columns">Offer 5</li>
    <li class="small-6 large-3 columns">Offer 6</li>
    <li class="small-6 large-3 columns">Offer 7</li>
    <li class="small-6 large-3 columns">Offer 8</li>
    <li class="small-6 large-3 columns">Offer 9</li>
    <li class="small-6 large-3 columns">Offer 10</li>
    <li class="small-6 large-3 columns">Offer 11</li>
    <li class="small-6 large-3 columns">Offer 12</li>
</ul>
```

I want to add some spacing between the blocks, a margin, but I don't want to use pixel values because this will take up to much screen real estate. If for example I wanted a 20px margin, how could I convert that into a percentage and ensure it's consistent across all browsers?

It's a little confusing to me.

Comment: you should use `em` instead of percent in margin

Comment: @TheMechanic care to explain in an answer bud?

Comment: An em is used for typography, it's an alternative to using pixels when defining the size of a font ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_(typography))). Percentages **are** used for the margin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i can see the zurb foundation framework uses padding on the columns div to create gutter/spacing between the things "inside the column div".
If you where to add some margin after a column div you will have to recalculate the width of all the columns to make space for the margin.

If you instead would like to change the padding of the columns to be in percentages you should override the .column/.columns css rule:

```
.column,
.columns {
    padding: 0 1.5625%;
}
```

You can use the result = target/context rule to calculate the percentage, here I assumed that you would like the padding to be 15px (as the default foundation padding) when the total width (context) is 960px. Calculating the percentage: 15/960 = 0.015625 which is 1.5...%. 
You'll probably want to experiment with a little larger padding percentage since 1.5% looks good when you have a 960px container but it will fast look really cramped, when the container is 480 the total space between columns will be half (15px instead of 30px) of what it is in the original implementation (since the context has been halved).

Another disadvantage of having a relative padding is that if you would like to be able to nest columns, inside each other, then you'll change the context and therefore you'll have to recalculate the percentages.

Answer (score 1):

How to find the the percentage width of a 20px margin? Divide it by by the width of it's parent. Assuming 960px width and 20px margin, it's 960/20 = 0,02083333, so ~2%.

As for browser consistency, here's where things can get messy. What's 50% of 101? 50,5, obviously, but since there's no such thing as half a pixel, browsers attempt to guess what it should round tve value to.

IE - in it's eternal wisdom - rounds everything up, meaning you may end up with boxes wider than their parent, often breaking the layout. Webkit rounds everything down to prevent layouts from breaking, and Gecko does a mix of both to avoid void pixels that come from only rounding down.

In general, use percentage values that add up to something just below 100%. 99.9% is almost always enough, but you will need to find the maximum value for your design.

I often find that floating the last child of a row to the right and removing it's (right) margin makes for the most structured layouts, but that's more of a general tip than relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify pixels via percentage unless the property it takes it's percentage from is defined in pixels.

A percentage is a percentage of the dimensions of the first positioned parent. If your positioned parent has it's dimensions specified in pixels then it possible.

However if you want to use percentages to take up a certain amount of the user's viewport then you have to accept that pixel accuracy is no longer possible.

e.g.

```
#offers {
   width: 1000px;
   position: relative;
}

#offers li {
   width: 10%; // Width is now 100px
}
```

But

```
#offers li {
   width: 10%; // Assuming there is no positioned parent then width is now 10% width of the users viewport and width depends on viewport size
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use pixels. And I know pixels can't be specified using a percentage, but there is math you can do to get a very close approximation of the pixel value as a percentage - I believe this is where the debate about using absurd decimal places for percentages came from.

Comment: @SparkDesigns No you can't because without using pixels you are taking percentage from the viewport. If the viewport is 500 pixels wide then 10% is 50, if it is 1000 it is 100... this is the whole point of percentages. You want to look into `em` sizing which is based on the users default font size and is much more consistent.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, I set the width via percentage, I don't touch the height at all, so let's say I have a 500px width div inside of a 900px container, if I understand correctly the percentage would be:

```
#sample-div
{
     width: 55.55555555555556%; /* 500/900 = 0.5555555555555556 */
}
```

read more about this from [here](http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/15295/responsive-web-design-when-to-use-px-vs-on-margins-and-padding/p1)

**or one other way is**

**don’t use px units, use em units**

The px vs em debate is a long one but em units have proven themselves useful in responsive web design. Using em units should be familiar to most web developers, but worth reviewing. An em unit is a relative unit of measurement based on the parent element.

The most common example is font-size, if you wanted to set a heading font-size (20px) based on your body font-size (10px) in em units:

```
20px &divide; 10px = 2em

target &divide; context = result

body { font: 100%/1.5 serif; /* 16px */  }

h1 {  font-size: 2em; /* 32px */ }

@media (min-width: 600px) {
   body { font: 112.5%; /* 18px */  }
   h1 {    /* Do nothing! I'll automatically be 36px */ }
}
```

you can read more from [here](http://www.netmagazine.com/features/five-steps-gettin-flexy-responsive-web-design)

Comment: That's what I was looking for. This rings a bell.